# Mis Componentes React no se actualizan

Tags: reactjs, vite, server-side-rendering

Estoy siguiendo un curso de React usando vite. Resulta que cuando inicio el ordenador todo va bien pero pasado un tiempo no se ejecutan los cambios de estado en mis componentes react.
Utilizo: **npm run dev APLICACION** para ejecutar la aplicación
Para ver los cambios hechos en el código tengo que terminar el servidor y eliminar el uso del puerto con **npx kill NumPuerto**
Para volver a cargar el servidor nuevamente con
**npm run dev Aplicacion**
Solo así se ven los cambios nuevamente. ¿a alguien le ha pasado algo similar?

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Answer (score 0):

yo lo acabo de solucionar al cambiarme de terminal...yo he estado trabajando con wsl y en el mismo visual studio ejecutaba el comando `npm run dev` pero los cambios que hacia nunca se actualizaba, solo si mata el servidor e iniciaba el proceso otra vez.
Pero en cambio si te cambias de terminal a la de windows (es donde tengo el proyecto), se actualizaba sin problemas

Comment: Esto realmente no responde a la pregunta. Si tienes una pregunta diferente, la puedes formular haciendo clic en [Formular una pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). También puedes [ofrecer una recompensa](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) para atraer más atención a esta pregunta cuando tengas suficiente [reputación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation). - [Desde revisión](/review/late-answers/397673)